# Procedure or Function expects parameter which was not supplied?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

When I run the code below I get an error message:

> Msg 201, Procedure stp_DespatchedJob, Line 0 Procedure or Function
>   'stp_DespatchedJob' expects parameter '@JobStatusId', which was not
>   supplied

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp_DespatchedJob]
(
  @jobId as bigint,
  @DriverId int,
  @HasPda bit,
  @enablePda bit,
  @IsAdvanceJob bit,
  @IsAutodespatchedJob bit,
  @Controller varchar(100),
  @JobStatusId int

)
AS
Begin

     if(@enablepda=1 and @haspda=1)
     BEGIN
         UPDATE BOOKING
            SET BookingStatusId=@JobStatusId,JobOfferDateTime=getdate()
                ,DriverId=@DriverId,despatchdatetime=getdate()
                ,Despatchby = @Controller
         where id=@jobId


     END

     ELSE
     BEGIN

       declare @fleetMasterId int
        select @fleetMasterId=fleetMasterId from fleet_DriverQueueList where driverId=@driverId and status=1


         UPDATE BOOKING
            SET BookingStatusId=2,DriverId=@DriverId,despatchdatetime=getdate(),FleetMasterId=@FleetMasterId,Despatchby = @Controller
           where id=@jobId

      END


     if(@IsAdvanceJob=1 and  @IsAutodespatchedJob=1) 
     BEGIN

         Update booking_autodespatch set  despatched=1 where bookingId=@jobId
     END

End
```

What does this mean? Why am I getting this error? How to get rid of that ?

Comment: What error message do you get ?

Comment: Msg 201, Procedure stp_DespatchedJob, Line 0 Procedure or Function 'stp_DespatchedJob' expects parameter '@JobStatusId', which was not supplied

Comment: Stored procs follow deferred name compilation which means object existence will not be checked until runtime.So I ran your code and I was able to create and alter it with out any issues.Other than posted code ,are you trying to execute SP

Comment: Please, post the actual call you are making.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all procedure parameters are mandatory, there are two ways of calling it correctly:

1) **directly** (not recommended)

EXEC dbo.stp_DespatchedJob 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 'ctrl', 7

2) **using [named parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177436(v=sql.105).aspx)** (recommended)

```
EXEC [dbo].[stp_DespatchedJob]
  @jobId = 1,
  @DriverId = 2,
  @HasPda = 1,
  @enablePda = 1,
  @IsAdvanceJob = 1,
  @IsAutodespatchedJob = 1,
  @Controller = 'ctrl',
  @JobStatusId = 7
```

Failing to provide values for all your parameters will lead to errors similar to what you have received. If you have some values that are almost always the same (e.g. `JobStatusId = 1`), you can specify it with a default value in the procedure prototype:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp_DespatchedJob]
(
  @jobId as bigint,
  @DriverId int,
  @HasPda bit,
  @enablePda bit,
  @IsAdvanceJob bit,
  @IsAutodespatchedJob bit,
  @Controller varchar(100),
  @JobStatusId int = 1
)
AS
```

and you no longer have to provide a value for `@JobStatusId` when calling the procedure.

Comment: THANK YOU SOOO MUCH SIR , THIS FIXED IT FOR ME, BEEN STUCK ON THAT FOR MONTHS, YOU ARE A STAR !!

Comment: Thanks for this. Helped me in 2020!